# Persistent Union-Find with occasional removals

Tags: algorithm, persistence, union-find

I have a set of half a million items stored in the database and need the following operations:

- [`union(x, y)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Union) just like in Union-Find
- `findAll(x)` finding all `y` such that `find(x) == find(y)`
- `ununion(x, y)` reverting a former union operation

This is a practical problem, for which the following is known

- The partitions will be typically small (less than 100 elements), but there's no guarantee.
- The speed of `union` operation doesn't matter much.
- `findAll` has to be fast and needs to be implemented in SQL (without recursion / CONNECT BY).
- Sometimes, we find out, that some `union` was actually wrong and need to undo it, while keeping all the previous and following `union`s. This operation is rare enough, so the speed doesn't matter.
- It's not necessary that `findAll` sees changes done by the other operations immediately. Some post-processing would be OK.

---

The classical Union-Find algorithm needs path compression (or a variant) for efficiency and allows no edge deletions (even without path compression). I'm aware of [Dynamic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity), but it looks like non-applicable to my use case.

I guess, we can't use it, as the speed of `findAll` is the most important. Probably, we should link all nodes to the root directly.

Concerning `ununion`, my only idea is to store all `union` operations separately, and on `ununion`, remove all links from the corresponding partition and redo all related `union`s.

This sounds rather brute-force like...

---

Before starting implementing anything, I'm asking if there's smarter algorithm?

Comment: From the 3 operations you require, which do not include `find`, the obvious implementation is to have `union(x,y)` create an edge between `x` and `y`, and `findAll(x)` do a BFS.  Are you really sure you don't want to do any kind of recursion in the SQL?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'm using MySQL which has no CONNECT BY and Hibernate, so I guess, I really want no recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a hash function for sets, and store it with each `x` in the database in an indexed column.  On constructing a `union(x, y)` you can calculate the new hash value and store it.  On `findAll` the use of this index means that you will be only comparing sets with a good chance of being the same, which makes it reasonably fast.  And there is nothing fancy in the lookup, so you can reasonably implement it in naive SQL.